# Cannot to connect to a Cassandra DB from localhost

Tags: opensolaris, ruby-on-rails, cassandra

I don't know if I'm on the right site,
I installed OpenSolaris a single cassandra node, I don't have other node.
On the same server, I install Ruby 1.8 with the gem Cassandra.

If I try to connect from my computer to the Cassandra node through the ruby gem cassandra, I can connect perfectly, if I try to to the same from the ruby gem cassandra in the server, it says that there is no listening on 127.0.0.1.

I can connect locally to the instance using telnet 127.0.0.1 9160 and it works...

any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: The correct error message is "ThriftClient::NoServersAvailable: No live servers in ["127.0.0.1:9160"] since Sat May 22 16:47:04 +0200 2010."

Comment: it seems that Funa's gem or Thrift is not supported by OpenSolaris...

Comment: @djyod could you mark the question as solved ?